# Fail to render : Page not found: /common_script.zul

Tags: java, zk

I recently being assign to a new department and to my worst nightmare, i am asked to support a piece of website coded with ZK with no documentation, no handover, and no one knows the system. But, i am blessed with the laptop where the previous developer develop this system on.

With a few days of linking the bots, i manage to found out that this website is indeed written in ZK, Birt Report and the IDE is Eclipse Galileo 3.5.1 I have quite a bit of knowledge in Spring, hence i am able to hack the code to only certain extend.

I hit a road block in Eclipse IDE, everytime it is trying to render the ZK pages so i can modify the screen. I always getting the "Fail to render : Page not found: /common_script.zul" error when i am on the ZUL Visual Editor.

Any idea where should i start to be able to render the ZK page? I find manually edit the .zul XML is pretty much impossible for the enhancements i need to do.

The ZK version is "ZK 5.0.5 2010110316" base on the view page source.

Comment: It's tough to say without more information. I'd recommend learning the basic of the ZK framework rather than diving into the mix of it blind. Make a HelloWorld ZK application or work through some tutorials online. Once you see all the basics of how a ZK application works (web.xml, zk.xml, .zul files, Java controllers, etc.) you'll be better able to interpret and debug the code you've been given. 5.0.5 is pretty old, you'll want appropriate tutorials. Ignore anything MVVM (came in v6.5) or use of [`SelectorComposer`]. You want tutorials about focused on `GenericForwardComposer`. Good luck.

Comment: zk is easier to maintain than other web apps :)

Comment: have you moved anything or files in the system?

Comment: @SeanConnolly Thank you for the advice, i was trying to built the eclipse with ZK and etc from scratch initially. But i failed to get it compile the existing project :(

Comment: @Nikos i dont know if anyone move things prior to me. But i do know that i have not change the Eclipse and the built-in Tomcat (i have restore from the backup which i made when i first have my hands on this laptop)